# How to 'repair' a GNU Screen session's terminal after spilling binary data onto stdout?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, terminal-emulator

I suspect we've all done something similar to this:

```
> gpg -d oops.tar.gz.gpg

�@�����÷b�ʘ�K����L:EX��w�)܇�՘����5�     ���#[�7��ﻳ@�Ǎ
�n�Kr��Kyb��3�X���E�_?*A�wp��������DH���gМ�n�(�4-
```

resulting in command characters being sent to the terminal and causing all kinds of strange things to happen. Ordinarily, one would type `reset` and the terminal would go back to normal.

However, when using Screen, corruption seems to persist after `reset`, resulting in the status line being duplicated and various other entertaining effects. Is there any way of restoring everything to a sensible default in a manner similar to `reset`?

Comment: Doesn't "ctrl-a shift-z enter" fix it either?

Comment: @mosvy I think that helped. It doesn't clear the name of the window, which turned out to be the cause of some of the problems, but I think both were needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

typing `stty sane` may work. It is equivalent to

`stty cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iutf8 -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok  -echonl  -noflsh  -xcase  -tostop  -echoprt  echoctl echoke`

which sets all special characters to their default values

Comment: Or it mayn't. Try `printf '\e)0\x0eabc'; stty sane`.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the problems actually result from the name of the Screen window containing weird characters. The name can be changed back to something without control characters using `C-a A` to edit the window name. Standard Emacs key combinations can be used (e.g. `C-a a` `C-k`).

`C-a Z` will then reset the terminal to its default values. (Thanks to @mosvy.)